# libmodbus: modbus_mapping_new() not working correctly?

Tags: c, modbus

I have written my own Modbus Slave based on the example (unit-test-server.c) from the libmodbus library (v3.1.4). However, it's not working because of a problem that I don't know how to solve: the modbus_mapping_new() function seems to be allocating memory for the wrong data?!

This is what I'm doing, and according to the [documentation](https://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.1.4/modbus_mapping_new.html) this should allocated memory for 7 holding registers:

```
mb_mapping = modbus_mapping_new(0, 0, 7, 0);
```

What's actually happening is this:

[image]

```
printf("NB_BITS = %d\nSTART_BITS = %d\nNB_INPUT_BITS = %d\nSTART_INPUT_BITS = %d\nNB_INPUT_REGISTERS = %d\nSTART_INPUT_REGISTERS = %d\nNB_REGISTERS = %d\nSTART_REGISTERS = %d\n", mb_mapping->nb_bits, mb_mapping->start_bits, mb_mapping->nb_input_bits, mb_mapping->start_input_bits, mb_mapping->nb_input_registers, mb_mapping->start_input_registers, mb_mapping->nb_registers, mb_mapping->start_registers); // DEBUG OUTPUT
```

^^ These are all the values that can be set in the [modbus_mapping_t structure](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/blob/master/src/modbus.h).

If there is anybody familiar with the libmodbus library here: Am I misunderstanding the documentation or what is going on here?

Right now I'm getting a SegFault because modbus_mapping_new() hasn't allocated memory for the 7 holding registers I'm writing to.

Comment: where exactly segfault has occurred? You find it using a debugger or it's only suggestions?

Comment: The SegFault occurs in exactly this line: mb_mapping->tab_registers[i] = i * 2; Here I'm writing to memory that hasn't been allocated by modbus_mapping_new() even thought it should have. I found it using Valgrind.

Comment: it's really strange, looking through the sources it should `malloce'd` exactly 7 `mb_mapping->tab_registers = (uint16_t *) malloc(nb_registers * sizeof(uint16_t));` it's allocate something at all or here is a `NULL` ?

Comment: The function seems to interpret my parameters like this: "Allocate memory for 0 input_bits at address 7", which, of course, doesn't make much sense. But that is what's happening as you can see on the screenshot in my original posting. I'm certain that some allocation is happening as the if condition right after the mapping does not become true.

Comment: from your debug output here is `mb_mapping->nb_registers == 0` it should be 7. `mb_mapping->nb_registers = nb_registers;` if it `0` then `mb_mapping->tab_registers = NULL;`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wasn't clear, sorry. The whole mb_mapping structure isn't NULL, but the tab_registers element is. I just verified it by adding additional debug output to the code. The desired outcome would be: NB_REGISTERS = 7, START_REGISTERS = 0. And everything else can also be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run my program on my MacBook and everything works perfectly fine! modbus_mapping_new() allocates memory for the registers (500 in this case) and Modbus Masters are retrieving the correct values from my Slave.

[image]

I guess that means that the code has a problem with the CPU architecture of the Nvidia Jetson TX2 that I run my code on originally?! How do I solve this such that it can run correctly on the Jetson too?

Oddly enough I had the exact same code run perfectly fine on the Jetson once too, some months ago. I have absolutely no idea what might have changed ...

[Edit]

I finally figured it out: Somehow the libmodbus versions seem to have got mixed up. While the LIBMODBUS_VERSION_STRING variable contained "3.1.4", the latest version, there was also libmodbus 3.0.6 installed via the Ubuntu packet sources. I purged the latter from the system and reinstalled libmodbus 3.1.4 from the official git repository. Now everything works fine.